# How do you "preview" user actions like resize or editing in GoDiagrams?

Tags: winforms, controls

- The GoDiagram object model has a GoDocument.
- GoViews have a reference to a GoDocument.
- If the user does any modification on the diagramming surface, a GoDocument.Changed event is raised with the relevant information in the event arguments.

I would like to be notified when some user-actions happen, so that I can confer with my Controller (disallow/cancel it if need be) and then issue view-update orders from there that actually modify the **Northwoods GoDiagram** third party component.
The Changed event is a notification that something just happened (past tense) - Doing all of the above in the event handler results in a .... (*wait for it*)... StackOverflowException. (GoDocument.Changed handler > Updates GoDocument > Firing new Changed events.. )

So question, how do I get a BeforeEditing or BeforeResizing kind of notification model in GoDiagrams? Has anyone who's been there lived to tell a tale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFYI...
The component-vendor recommendation is to subclass and override appropriate methods for this. Override the bool CanXXX() method, raise a cancelable custom event. If the subscriber returns false, bail out (**return false to abort the user action**) of CanXXX. 
**No built-in mechanism for this in GoDiagrams.**

> For example, you could define a
>   CustomView.ObjectResizing cancelable
>   event.  In your override of
>   GoToolResizing.CanStart, you can raise
>   that event.  If the
>   CancelEventArgs.Cancel property
>   becomes true, you would have
>   CanStart() return false.

Source http://www.nwoods.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=2745

Answer (score 0):

The event arguments (GoChangedEventArgs) for the change event has a property IsBeforeChanging which indicates whether the change event was raised from the "RaiseChanging" method (true), or the RaiseChanged (false).  That should tell you whether the change has occurred yet, but I know of no way to cancel it.

The best I can suggest is instead of checking if the change is allowed and performing it, check if the change is *not* allowed, and if it isn't call the "Undo" method on the arguments in the change event.  So essentially:

```
OnChanged(GoChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if(NotAllowed)
  {
    e.Undo();
  }
}
```